# Rails 4 form with namespace generates undesired params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form, strong-parameters

I have this on my form

```
= simple_form_for polymorphic_path([:admin, @place]), :url => admin_places_path(@place), :method => 'post' ...



Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓","authenticity_token"=>"UzvU072fWHiuSDD0BsIEaLqmIKJWujiFzWval8MripU=", "/admin/places"=>{"name"=>"My Name", "description"=>"My Description"}, "commit"=>"Ok"
```

Unpermitted parameters: utf8, authenticity_token, /admin/places, commit

What I want is the param "/admin/places" become "place" and that way my params.require(:place).permit(...) work. I think that way looks better and was wondering how to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the polymorphic_path to @place only. simple_form_for(as form_for) expected a object that represent the Place itself. Now using the params.require(:place)... works